# Not sure how to get this regex to stop returning array

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

The following:

```
$key = "[[question(8)]]";

preg_match( '/\((.*?)\)/', $key, $questionID );
print_r( $questionID );
```

outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => (8)
    [1] => 8
)
```

I just want it to output `8`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[preg_match](http://php.net/preg_match) simply returns an array.

You need to do something like:

```
$questionID = $questionID[1];
```

From the manual:

> If $matches [third argument] is provided, then it is filled with the results of search.
>   `$matches[0]` will contain the text that matched the full pattern,
>   `$matches[1]` will have the text that matched the first captured
>   parenthesized subpattern, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The first index is the entire match of your regex. The second index is the first capture group. Capture groups are identified by `()`. So your first (and only) capture group in this case is `(.*?)`. If you had a second capture group it would be in the next index of the array.

If you just want to return the first capture group, do `$questionID[1]`

Answer (score 0):

Well if you just need that number you don't need array at all. To not return a array, use a function that returns a `string`, like `preg_replace` does.

```
$key = "[[question(8)]]";

$questionID = preg_replace( '/[^0-9]/', '', $key );

var_dump ( $questionID );
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php